# Oracle OCI library fails when packaged in AppImage

Tags: c, oracle, appimage

The following code sets up an OCI (Oracle Call Interface) environment, which must be done before attempting to connect to a database. It works fine when compiled and linked as a normal program, but when I attempt to package it into an AppImage, `OCIEnvCreate()` returns `OCI_ERROR`.

If I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/` the AppImage works as expected. Apparently the library trickery done by the AppImage builder fails somehow on the Oracle libraries. Is there some trick to make them work in an AppImage?

(Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't a solution, since I'm trying to not have to install the Oracle library on every client.)

Tested on CentOS 8, GCC 8.4.1 and 10.2.1, oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64

```c
#include <oratypes.h>
#include <oci.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    OCIEnv        *envhp;
    int status;
    status = OCIEnvCreate((OCIEnv **)&envhp,
            (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT,
            (void  *)0, (void  * (*)(void  *, size_t))0,
            (void  * (*)(void  *, void  *, size_t))0,
            (void (*)(void  *, void  *))0,
            (size_t)0, (void  **)0);
      if (OCI_ERROR == status) {
        printf("Failed: OCIEnvCreate()\n");
      } else if (OCI_SUCCESS == status) {
        printf("Success: OCIEnvCreate()\n");
      } else {
        printf("Other return status '%d' from OCIEnvCreate()\n", status);
      }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the Oracle client installed on the client machine.  Oracle provides the Instant Client which is designed to be a minimal client that can be installed as part of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appimage builder didn't copy all the OCI shared libraries to the AppImage automatically. Adding each .so file to the `linuxdeploy` command line with `--library /path/to/library.so` for each library file fixed the problem. Presumably some .so->.so dependency wasn't resolved by the automatic process.